# List of dictionaries to list of one property's values

Tags: python

Id like to turn a list of dictionaries to a list that only contains the values to each `url` property.

So it would work like this:

**Input**

```
[
  {"id": 0, "url": "https://example.com/0"},
  {"id": 1, "url": "https://example.com/1"},
  {"id": 2, "url": "https://example.com/2"},
  {"id": 3, "url": "https://example.com/3"},
]
```

**Output**

```
[
  "https://example.com/0",
  "https://example.com/1",
  "https://example.com/2",
  "https://example.com/3",
]
```

With Javascript I would just use `map` and return the `url` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a list comprehension would be the idiomatic way to go:

```py
result = [x['url'] for x in original_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

##### list comprehension

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
l = [
  {"id": 0, "url": "https://example.com/0"},
  {"id": 1, "url": "https://example.com/1"},
  {"id": 2, "url": "https://example.com/2"},
  {"id": 3, "url": "https://example.com/3"},
]

[d['url'] for d in l]
```

output:

```
['https://example.com/0',
 'https://example.com/1',
 'https://example.com/2',
 'https://example.com/3']
```

##### map + itemgetter

or, `map` + [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)

```
from operator import itemgetter
list(map(itemgetter('url'), l))
```

output:

```
['https://example.com/0',
 'https://example.com/1',
 'https://example.com/2',
 'https://example.com/3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
ld = [
  {"id": 0, "url": "https://example.com/0"},
  {"id": 1, "url": "https://example.com/1"},
  {"id": 2, "url": "https://example.com/2"},
  {"id": 3, "url": "https://example.com/3"},
]
lurl1 = [x["url"] for x in ld]  # more idiomatic list comprehension
lurl2 = list(map(lambda x: x["url"], ld))  # if you really want map
```